# Looping JS object only works with return statement otherwise it throw undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

This first method with return statement inside JSX works correctly

```
  <div>
    {this.state.list.map(item => {
      return <h6>{item.location.formattedAddress[0]}</h6>
    })}
  </div>
```

But this normally should give the same result :

```
 render() {
    const listItems = this.state.list.map((item, index) => (
        <h6>{item.location.formattedAddress[0]}</h6>
    ));
    return (
      {listItems}
    )
 }
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Also it runs on mounting the page rather than when executing the function to load the dat from API, please someone assist

Comment: Ideally both of them will behave the same unless you have something in render method that returns before `{this.state.list.map(item => {
      return <h6>{item.location.formattedAddress[0]}</h6>
    })}` is executed

Comment: Instead of `return ({listItems})` use `return (listItems)` (*remove the `{}`*) because that returns an object with the property `listItems`. Secondly check for `this.state.list` before using `map` on it in case your state is not yet filled.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

---

This is the first method like you did:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [
        { id: 1, title: 'React' },
        { id: 2, title: 'Angular' },
        { id: 3, title: 'Vue' }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.list && this.state.list.map(li => (
          <h2 key={li.id}>{li.title}</h2>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div>
```

---

And this is the second method that you expected it to work

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [
        { id: 1, title: 'React' },
        { id: 2, title: 'Angular' },
        { id: 3, title: 'Vue' }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    const listItems = this.state.list ? this.state.list.map(li => (
      <h2 key={li.id}>{li.title}</h2>
    )) : '';
    return <div>{listItems}</div>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"><div>
```

---

I added some small checks before rendering to ensure that you won't get the error:  *Cannot read property 'map' of undefined*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to turn listItems in to a method like `renderListItems()` and add a return before mapping the array.

```
renderListItems = () => {
    return this.state.list.map((item, index) => (
        <h6>{item.location.formattedAddress[0]}</h6>
    ));
}
```

Then call it in your render method like

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderListItems()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Hope this helps :)